# Pivot Tables- Set The Table in a Tabular Form using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

To whom it may concern,

I am trying to develop a Pivot Table in Excel using Apache POI and Java. However, I want it in a "Tabular Form" with dropdown menus for each of the rows. To be more specific, I want the top row of the pivot table to be shown like this (apologies for part of the top row being cut off):
[image]

Whereas in reality, the top row turns out to be this:
[image]

The code which I have done to try and generate the pivot table is as follows:

```
    int count = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < s2.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()-1; j++)
        {
            try {
            Row r = s1.getRow(j+1);
            Row r2 = s3.createRow(count);
            //System.out.println(r.getCell(27).getStringCellValue());
            if (r.getCell(8).getStringCellValue().equals(r.getCell(11).getStringCellValue()) && 
            (!r.getCell(8).getStringCellValue().equals("N/A")))
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < 30; b++)
                {
                r2.createCell(b).setCellValue(r.getCell(b).getStringCellValue());
                System.out.println(j);
                
                }
                count++;
            }
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        AreaReference a = new AreaReference("A1:AD344",SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
        CellReference c = new CellReference("AF6");
        XSSFPivotTable iRxBest = s3.createPivotTable(a,c);
        iRxBest.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setRowHeaderCaption("Drug Name");
        iRxBest.addReportFilter(27);
        iRxBest.addReportFilter(10);
          iRxBest.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setUpdatedVersion((short)6); 
          for (int q = 0; q < 30; q++)
          {
              
          if(q != 1 && q != 7 && q != 9 && q != 10 &&  (q < 12 || q > 22) && (q < 25 || q > 28))
                  {
              
                  
          TreeSet <String>uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>();
           for (int r = a.getFirstCell().getRow()+1; r < a.getLastCell().getRow()+1; r++) {
                uniqueItems.add(s3.getRow(r).getCell(q).getStringCellValue());
               }
               System.out.println("SIZE IZ: "  + uniqueItems.size());
                iRxBest.addRowLabel(q);
                
       CTPivotField pField1 =iRxBest.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(q);
       // pField1.setAutoShow(false);
        pField1.setDefaultSubtotal(false);
        pField1.setOutline(false);
//        pField1.setSubtotalTop(false);
//        pField1.setSubtotalCaption("");
    
//     pField1.setOutline(false);
//      pField1.setSubtotalTop(false);
//        pField1.setSubtotalCaption("");
        
        for (int r = 0; r < uniqueItems.size(); r++)
        {
             pField1.getItems().getItemArray(r).unsetT();
             pField1.getItems().getItemArray(r).setX((long)r);
        }
        for (int r = 343; r > uniqueItems.size()-1; r--)
        {
            pField1.getItems().removeItem(r);
        }
        pField1.getItems().setCount(uniqueItems.size());
        for (String xyz: uniqueItems)
        {
            iRxBest.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(q).getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(xyz);
        }

         CTExtensionList extList = pField1.addNewExtLst();
           CTExtension ext = extList.addNewExt();
           String extXML = 
              "<x14:pivotField"
            + " xmlns:x14=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main\""
            + " fillDownLabels=\"1\"/>";
           org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject xlmObject = org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject.Factory.parse(extXML);
           ext.set(xlmObject);
           ext.setUri("{2946ED86-A175-432a-8AC1-64E0C546D7DE}");  
          
          }
            //iRxBest.addRowLabel(13);
          }
            count = 1;
```

No effective solution has been found based on how to put the pivot table in this kind of form using Java. If you know of any way as to how to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Looks like your createPivotTable method is putting everything except the Drug Name into the Values area, so they don't get filter drop-downs as a result. If your goal is to allow the user to filter the rows based on values (measures), then they would use the filter drop-down on the Drug Name and select something from the Value Filters sub-menu.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. Where is the "Values area" which you are talking about?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-field-list-to-arrange-fields-in-a-pivottable-43980e05-a585-4fcd-bd91-80160adfebec

Comment: Thanks for the link. This does tell you how to rearrange pivot table filters in excel, but what I'm really asking is how do I put the pivot table in tabular form using Java code.

Comment: Right, but my point is that it looks to me like you have already put it in tabular form (difficult to see from your screenshot because it only shows the header row) but that the problem is your fields are in the wrong part of the pivot table.